# Сделал скрипт, он работает. Теперь хочу сделать то же самое, но при помощи ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Друзья, хочу заранее предупредить, к изучению ООП я только что подошел, не судите строго.

В общем, в папке лежат txt-файлы, которые читаются встроенной функцией file, затем каждый файл обрабатывается с собственными настройками (названия файлов всегда одни и те же). Поэтому все выглядит следующим образом (кратко):

```
$files = array_diff(scandir($folder), array('..','.'));
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        if($file == 'Файл1.txt')
        {
            ... (здесь много всяких рег. выражений, переменных, свойственных этому файлу, набор примерно один тот же)
        }
    }
```

Поэтому я решил сделать то же самое, но при помощи ООП, т.к много циклов и ветвлений, что можно запутаться. Сделал класс, объявил public-переменные и т.д. Но как создать объекты, если раньше все делалось при помощи foreach? Каждый объект имеет название файла... Спасибо!

Comment: Зачем вам создавать класс для чтения файлов? Только ради оопэ? Так  тогда просто берите стандартные средства php в оопэ, и используйте. Будет и кода меньше, и работать быстро: `$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__)));

foreach ($iter as $file) {
    $iter->isDot() ?: print $file . '<br>';
}`

Comment: О существовании RecursiveDirectoryIterator я даже и не знал, спасибо. Сейчас почитаю...

Comment: @Эдуард не для чтения, а для обработки разных файлов разными методами.

Comment: если вы знаете названия файлов, которые обрабатываете, то зачем читать директорию вообще и проверять? пройдитесь по массиву известных имен, если файл существует, то делайте дело, нет дак дальше.